# HTML MP4 embed trouble

Tags: html, css, video, embed

I'm a beginner to HTML and need some help... This thing has been driving me crazy-I want to embed a HTML snippet in my site so that a video plays once without showing the controls... I also wanted it to work on many browsers, and after 2 days of research I achieved the code below (woo-hoo!). The only trouble is that when I put the code in the the snippet in the program, I cannot control its position (I want to put a small image above it and can't get the video behind it...)
Please help me! Can the code be fixed or do you know alternatives? (I don't want to modify the header section or install scripts)

```
<video wdith="600" height="300" autoplay>
  <source src="https://sites.google.com/site/privateforsharingfilesbytt/home/docs/Eng.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[screenshot](https://sites.google.com/site/privateforsharingfilesbytt/home/docs/Screenshot.jpg)
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like an issue with positioning and formatting -- not with the actual embedding.

Comment: For clarity, are you attempting to get an image overlaid on top of the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example to overlay an `img` on a video:

```
<div>
    <img id="overlay_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/i5Gp6.png" width="150" height="150" />

    <video width="560" height="340" controls>
        <source src="http://media.html5media.info/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
</div>​
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QhZfZ/)

The idea is to place an image using an `img` tag. Then, I gave the image an `id` to I can adjust it's positioning in CSS. To have the image actually overlay on top of the video, I did `position: absolute` which allows me to set the position of the element relative to its' ancestor.

If you would like to move around the image, you will need to specify `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` positioning values.